# MySQL Privileges required to GRANT EVENT, EXECUTE, LOCK TABLES, and TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql5

I have an account, `user_a`, and I would like to grant all available permissions on `some_db` to `user_b`.  I have tried the following query:

```
GRANT 
    ALTER, ALTER ROUTINE, 
    CREATE, CREATE ROUTINE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE VIEW, 
    DELETE, DROP, EVENT, EXECUTE, 
    INDEX, INSERT, LOCK TABLES, 
    REFERENCES, SELECT, SHOW VIEW, 
    TRIGGER, UPDATE 
ON  `some_db`.* TO 'user_b'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

The result:

> Access denied for user 'user_a'@'%' to database 'some_db'

Some experimentation has shown me that the only permissions my account (`user_a`) is unable to grant are `EVENT`, `EXECUTE`, `LOCK TABLES`, and `TRIGGER`.

**What privileges are required for my account to `GRANT` these privileges to another user?**

If I run `SHOW GRANTS`, I get this output:

```
"GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'user_a'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '1234567890abcdef' WITH GRANT OPTION"
"GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON `some_other_unrelated_db`.* TO 'user_a'@'%'"
"GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `another_unrelated_db`.* TO 'user_a'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `GRANT OPTION` privilege, you can only grant privileges that you have. So, the following privileges cannot be granted to the `user_b`: EVENT, 
EXECUTE, LOCK TABLES, TRIGGER, UPDATE.

Comment: Yes, of course!  I feel like an idiot, I don't know how I missed that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Granting rights to users is limited to users who have the "grant" privileges globally.

Basically, you must have sufficient privileges to modify the global "grant" table... which gives you enough privileges to grant any privilege to any user.  Permissions are not stored in each schema... but rather stored in 1 table in the "mysql" schema.

For a list of users with the grant privilege try running this query:

```
SELECT User, Grant_priv from mysql.user;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I ran your query, and `user_a` does indeed have Grant_priv=='Y'.  Any other thoughts on what the problem might be?